# Pandas count in second dataframe if part of string is first df's content

Tags: python, pandas

having a simple DataFrame like this one:

```
    items
0   apple
1   car
2   tree
3   house
4   light
5   camera
6   laptop
7   watch
8   other
```

what would be a good way to count the times the individual words occur in a string in DF2:

```
    id        items
0   555       wall, grass, apple
1   124       bag, coffee, light
2   23123     bag, none, game
3   666       none, none, none
```

resulting in something like this

```
    items    count
0   apple    1
1   car      0
2   tree     0
3   house    0
4   light    1
5   camera   0
6   laptop   0
7   watch    0
8   other    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `value_counts` the exploded `items` columns of `df2` then map the result to `items` column of `df1`

```py
df1['count'] = (df1['items'].map(df2['items'].str.split(', ')
                                 .explode()
                                 .value_counts())
                .fillna(0).astype(int))
```

```
print(df1)

    items  count
0   apple      1
1     car      0
2    tree      0
3   house      0
4   light      1
5  camera      0
6  laptop      0
7   watch      0
8   other      0
```

Comment: Might be that I'm doing something wrong but this approach gave me: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: @Bishonen_PL You didn't use `df1['items'].map`?

Comment: apologies, my bad! When creating the DataFrame, I created it with a typo in which I set the columns to = [['items']] (double brackets). After fixing that, your solution works ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would split the items, explode, then reindex:

```
(df2['items'].str.split(', ')
    .explode().value_counts()
    .reindex(df1['items'], fill_value=0)
    .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

Output:

```
    items  count
0   apple      1
1     car      0
2    tree      0
3   house      0
4   light      1
5  camera      0
6  laptop      0
7   watch      0
8   other      0
```